# Need example for a topological space that isn't connected, but is compact

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

We know the topological space $(R,τ_1)$ is a connected space but it is not compact, $(R,τ_+)$ (which generated by $[a,b[$) is not connected space and it is not compact space, and $(R,τ_{cf})$ is connected and compact space.

Can someone give me an example of a compact space that isn't connected?

Comment: $\{0,1\}$ in $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.

Comment: @davidmitra what ???

Comment: Any finite Hausdorff space with more than one point.

Comment: I’d have posted the hint $$\huge\bullet\quad\bullet$$ if I’d been around!

Comment: What are all these spaces you list in your question?

Comment: The Stone space of a Boolean algebra is compact and totally disconnected. So you get infinitely many examples, as two Boolean algebras are isomorphic if and only if their Stone spaces are homeomorphic.

Comment: If you want to ask a different question, ask a new one. Edit another question in place of an old one is frowned upon. Some call it vandalism. Don't do that again. Ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $2$ or more elements will be compact and not connected because:

- Any finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ will be compact (by the Heine-Borel Theorem a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, which is true for any finite set)
- Any finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $2$ or more elements won't be connected

Comment: Surely a singleton is a connected set.

Comment: oops good point

Comment: @michaelblakeman you mean let X={1,2,3,4} and T=P(X) the space is compact but it is not connected

Answer (score 1):

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/) is an online encyclopedia of topological spaces inspired by Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*. It lists the following twelve compact spaces that are not connected. You can learn more about any of them by visiting the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2B%7EConnected).

Closed Ordinal Space $[0,\Gamma]$ ($\Gamma < \Omega$)

Closed Ordinal Space $[0,\Omega]$

Concentric Circles

Countable Fort Space

Either-Or Topology

Finite Discrete Topology

Maximal Compact Topology

Stone-Cech Compactification of the Integers

The Cantor Set

Tychonoff Plank

Uncountable Fort Space

Uncountable Modified Fort Space

Answer (score 0):

Take any two compact, connected topological spaces $X,Y$. Define their *discrete union* to be the disjoint union $X \coprod Y = (X \times \{0\}) \cup (Y \times \{1\})$ with the topology generated by all sets of the form $U \times \{0\}$ or $V \times \{1\}$ where $U \subset X$ is any open set in $X$ and $V \subset Y$ is any open subset of $Y$. Then $X \coprod Y$ is compact and has two components, one being $X \times \{0\}$ and the other $Y \times \{1\}$.